# Add custom font to all LinearLayout textviews

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-font

I add Linear Layout and multiple textviews programmatically and set custom font to texts,

i did it in the bellow way and its works perfectly .

**MainActivity 1:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        tv.setTextSize(40);    
        ll.addView(tv);
        Typeface face4=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");     
        tv.setTypeface(face4);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.trip)));    

        ImageView divider = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
         new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider.setLayoutParams(lp);
        divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(divider);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);      
        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv1.setTextSize(40);
        ll.addView(tv1);
        Typeface face1=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");     
        tv1.setTypeface(face1);
        tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.trip1)));

        ImageView divider1 = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = 
         new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        lp1.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        divider1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(divider1);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv2.setTextSize(40);
        ll.addView(tv2);
        Typeface face2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");     
        tv2.setTypeface(face2);
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.trip2)));

        ImageView divider3 = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = 
         new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        lp3.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        divider3.setLayoutParams(lp3);
        divider3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(divider3);       
                         }
                  }
```

**but as recall**

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets()
```

**with each text ,its an heavy way to apply custom font ,
I try to make custom view as bellow but it doesn't set the custom font to texts:**

**MainActivity:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    // add text view
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    tv.setTextSize(40);    
    ll.addView(tv);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.trip)));    

    ImageView divider = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
     new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    divider.setLayoutParams(lp);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    ll.addView(divider);


    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);      
    tv1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv1.setTextSize(40);
    ll.addView(tv1);
    tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.trip1)));

    ImageView divider1 = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = 
     new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
    lp1.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    divider1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
    divider1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    ll.addView(divider1);


    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv2.setTextSize(40);
    ll.addView(tv2);
    tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.trip2)));

    ImageView divider3 = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = 
     new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
    lp3.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    divider3.setLayoutParams(lp3);
    divider3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    ll.addView(divider3);
}}
```

**CustomTextView:**

```
    public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        //call the constructor which has the complete definition
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "BFantezy.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
```

any help will be appreciated , thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating your font from the assets every time, create a "FontFactory" and reuse the same one.

```
public class FontFactory {

private static Typeface t1;

public static Typeface getBFantezy(Context c) {
    if (t1 == null) {
        t1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "BFantezy.ttf");
    }
    return t1;
}


private static Typeface t2;

public static Typeface getOtherFont(Context c) {
    if (t2 == null) {
        t2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "OtherFont.ttf");
    }
    return t2;
}
}
```

Then to use it in your code you would just :

```
tv1.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getContext());
```

You no longer have to worry about creating the typeface. If it needs it, the factory will create it. You can add similar methods to handle any other typefaces you wish to use.

Comment: how to apply FontFactory to my code , and if that solve it why to create custom view so can i apply it to first code i wrote (MainActivity 1) , thanks for help as im new to android

Comment: The FontFactory is just a standard class that hands out the typeface objects and creates them if necessary. I amended my answer to show usage.

Comment: i add it like this :TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
         tv.setTextSize(40);    
         tv.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getContext()));
         ll.addView(tv);
   tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.trip))); but i gave red mark error under: getContext error is:1-create method getContext  () , or 2-change to GetBaseContext

Comment: There are many types of context (application/activity/service etc). Use whichever context is available to you in the code you are working from. getBaseContext is most likely as it is being suggested by the IDE.

Comment: please my friend i want to add another two different custom font to my font factory , how i will do it , thanks

Comment: repeat the code in the class above for each font. I'll amend the sample.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a custom TextView class and forgot to implement it..
try

```
CustomTextView tv1 = new CustomTextView(this);
```

instaed of

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
```

Likewise to all other TextView's

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a `Typeface` for each `TextView`. You could do something like `Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");` and after that for each `TextView` you can do `textview.setTypeface(face)`. Only call the method `createFromAsset()` once and reuse the object you get.